# Can I share my peers' class visit reports with the hiring committee?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track

I am currently a TT faculty at school A and I am applying to school B. I have my peers' letters from their annual class visits at school A. Can I share them with the hiring committee while applying to school B? I am thinking of including a link to those letters in my teaching statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your department gave you these letters as part of official communication, then they wanted you to have them and they are yours to use with I would say. I don't think your current department could claim that you cannot use them for applications, though they might claim copyright, for example (so you couldn't include them in a book you publish without the agreement of the authors).

Answer (score 1):

I think probably. But you should ask someone at school A. If A does not know you are applying to B and you do not want them to know then I think you should not share the letters. If you have seen them officially you could say you got good peer reviews.

Comment: I am keeping my job search confidential and I have requested the hiring committee to not disclose it to my school. Can I still share my peers' letters? PS: I have seen them officially.